# Consumer not getting allocated to message once the number of messages exceed number of concurrent consumers

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I want to understand how the consumers work for concurrent consumer once a message is consumed. Is the consumer bean discarded and new one created or is the consumer bean reused? I can see after rabbit mq server is set up, when I send a message, a consumer bean is instantiated.

My issue is that once the number of messages equals the number of concurrent consumers, the consumer in the message listener is null for the next message. I can see the Ack/Nack for previous messages in my logs and the prefetch is set to 1.

***XML configuration :***

```
<rabbit:admin connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory" />

<rabbit:template id="template" connection-factory="cachingConnectionFactory"
    retry-template="retryTemplate" />

<!-- CachingConnectionFactory -->
<bean id="cachingConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientConnectionFactorySSL" />
    <property name="username" value="${QM_USERNAME}" />
    <property name="password" value="${QM_PASSWORD}" />
    <property name="virtualHost" value="${QM_VIRTUALHOST}" />
    <property name="host" value="${QM_HOST}" />
    <property name="port" value="${QM_PORT}" />
</bean>

<!-- SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory -->
        <bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
            <property name="connectionFactory">
                <ref bean="cachingConnectionFactory" />
            </property>
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5" />
            <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="8" />
             <property name="startConsumerMinInterval" value="3000" />
        </bean>

<!-- Message listener container -->
        <bean id="springListenerContainerRABC"          class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingConnectionFactory" />
            <property name="queues" ref="rabbitDestinationRABC" />
            <property name="messageListener" ref="rabbitMessageListenerRABC" />
            **<property name="concurrentConsumers" value="4" />**
            <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="5" />
        </bean>

<!-- Message Listener -->
    <bean id="rabbitMessageListenerRABC" class="com.queue.rabbitmessaging.RabbitMQListener">
        **<property name="consumerType" value="XYZConsumer" />**
        <property name="responseSender" ref="XYZResponseSender" />
        <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor" />
        <property name="encoding" value="UTF-16BE" />
    </bean>

<!-- Consumers -->
<bean id="XYZConsumer" class="com.msg.consumer.XYZConsumer"
    scope="prototype" />
```

Here is what I see in the ***logs***:

```
00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - **Received message for consumer: XYZConsumer**

00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Message :: test1

00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Received message for consumer: XYZConsumer

00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Message :: test2

00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Received message for consumer: XYZConsumer

00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Message :: test3

00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Received message for consumer: XYZConsumer

00:17:49.725 [springListenerContainerRABC-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Message :: test4

[org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - **Received message for consumer: null**

[org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1] INFO RabbitMQListener - Message :: test5
```

***Consumer Code*** is as follows:

```
@EnableRabbit
@Service 
public class RabbitMQListener implements MessageListener {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    protected static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RabbitMQListener.class);

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    private RabbitSender responseSender;
    private String consumerType;
    private String encoding;

     public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    public void setTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }

    public void setResponseSender(RabbitSender responseSender) {
        this.responseSender = responseSender;
    }

    public void setConsumerType(String consumerType) {
        this.consumerType = consumerType;
    }

    public void setEncoding(String encoding) {
        this.encoding = encoding;
    }

    @Override
    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = Constants.CONTAINER_FACTORY, queues = "#{'${QM_QUEUES}'.split(',')}")
    public void onMessage(final Message arg0) {

        if (arg0 != null) {
            try {
                String message = new String(arg0.getBody());
                logger.info("Message Properties class: " + arg0.getClass());
                logger.info("Message Properties: " + arg0.getMessageProperties());
                logger.info("Received message for consumer: " + this.consumerType);
                logger.info("Message :: " + message);
                Object bean = applicationContext.getBean(this.consumerType);
                if (bean instanceof Consumer) {
                    logger.debug("Processing message for consumer: " + this.consumerType);
                    Consumer consumer = (Consumer)bean;
                    consumer.setMessage(message);
                    consumer.setResponseSender(responseSender);
                    logger.debug("Executing consumer: " + this.consumerType);
                    taskExecutor.execute(consumer);
                } else {
                    logger.info("Could not process message due to invalid consumer.");
                }

            } 
            catch (AmqpException e1) {
                logger.error("Spring AMQP error processing message.", e1.getMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e2) {
                logger.error("General error processing message.", e2.getMessage());
            }
        }
        else {
            logger.debug("message received is NULL");
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: No, the consumer is not  discarded, it runs continually. Your question is not clear; what do you mean by `the consumer in the message listener is null for the next message.`? Edit the question to make it clearer and show your code and configuration.

Comment: I have edited the question to give more information. My issue is that I can invoke correct/appropriate consumer only for the number of concurrentconsumers defined in my simplemessagelistenercontainer. For example if my concurrentconsumers is set to 4 till 4 messages in that queue, consumer is correctly called ( as seen in the logs). 5th message on wards the  consumer becomes null.

Comment: It's still not clear; you need to show the code that's logging `Received message for consumer: XYZConsumer` - it's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve with a prototype scope `XYZConsumer` bean since the `springListenerContainerRABC` has only one `rabbitMessageListenerRABC`. It's also not clear why you have a container factory as well as a container.

Comment: @GaryRussell
Container factory (SimpleRabbit) is used for establishing connection and listening to messages from queues. Listener container (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) is used to forward incoming messages to respective consumer. I have added the consumer code above. 

**it's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve with a prototype scope XYZConsumer bean since the springListenerContainerRABC has only one rabbitMessageListenerRABC** : I have multiple containers, each triggering its respective consumer bean.

Comment: It's a very strange architecture. It is very inefficient to create a new bean instance for each message. However, since `rabbitMessageListenerRABC` is a singleton; it's not clear how `this.consumerType` can be reset to `null` so something else is going on. Finally, it is not wise to run the consumers on a different thread; you risk losing messages in the case of a failure.

Comment: ok..now I understand what you meant by having both container factory and container. I don't need to use the container factory at all if I am setting the message listener through simple message listener container. What was happening was that the first 4 (concurrentconsumers count) messages were delivered to SimpleMessageListenerContainer. Once that was exhausted it starts using the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory which clearly does not set any messagelistener.  From logs -  [springListenerContainerRABC-1] & [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.RabbitListenerEndpointContainer#0-1]

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for your prompt help. Can you point me to an example where messagelistener can be set in SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory? Considering I have multiple consumers, is it possible?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do; the container factory is to support `@RabbitListener` annotated methods. Perhaps you could state your use case?

Answer (score 0):

The described behavior is consistent with not acking messages after they are received. RabbitMQ can be configured to [automatically acknowledge](https://wheleph.gitlab.io/2015/06/27/on-rabbitmq-automatic-ack-and-reliable-message-processing/) a message upon delivery.  If this does not happen, or is not configured, RabbitMQ will assume that the consumer is busy and will not deliver additional messages to it. You have to send an `ack` following the successful processing of a message to be able to receive the next message in the queue.